# will_paginate incremental table id

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a table and paginated to 20 per page:

```
    <% @num = 0%>
    <table>
    <tr>
      <th>id</th>
      <th>title</th>
    </tr>

    <% for authors in @authors%>
    <tr>
       <td><%= @num += 1 %></td>
       <td><%= authors.title %></td>
    </tr>
    <% end %>

</table>
<%= will_paginate @authors%>
```

I would like to make the id row to be continues. When I click on 1nd page i should see 1,2 3, 4 etc id. And when I click 2nd page I should see 21, 22, 23 etc but it just restarted to 1, 2 3

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of initializing `@num` to 0, set it to

```
 @authors.offset
```

When you do

```
@authors = Author.paginate(...)
```

What you get back is a `WillPaginate::Collection`. This is a subclass of Array, with methods such as the total number of pages, the number of items per page etc. In particular, `offset` gives the offset of the current page.

Comment: Thanks I'll try. I'm using rails 2.3

Comment: How can I count the total of the @authors?

Comment: There's a total_entries property too